# Search MYSQL database with Nodejs page

Tags: javascript, node.js

I´m trying to create a Search box in my website. But I cant get it to work.
I´m using Nodejs and EJS.

1. I have the HTML form with the action="" and method="" to get the text input email keyword.
2. Im passing that keyword to the POST route
3. Im doing the MYSQL query in that route, and Im bringing the result and passing it to the ejs view in the same POST route. (I couldnt find a way to do it in the GET route).
4. I get an error message saying "data is not defined" and it points to the EJS view. But I dont understand what the error is in the EJS view.

This is my code

perfil.ejs  (this is where the form is)

```
<div class="cssshowlaptopcampanas" style="font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; "> 
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-rows: 200px; margin-left: 400px; font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; ">
    <div class="" style=" padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 60px;">
        <h5 style="color: black; position: relative; top: 45px;">Busca tus anuncios</h5>
        <div class="container" style="position: relative; left: 20px;">
            <form action="/searchkeyemail" method="POST">
            <div class="search"> 
                <div class="row"> 
                    <div class="col-md-10"> 
                        <div class="search-1"> 
                            <i class='bx bx-search-alt'></i> 
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Digita tu email" name="search" value= " " id="search"  autofocus> 
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                    <button class="col-md-2" type="submit" style="background-color: #6351ce; color: white; border: none;" >Buscar</button> 
                </div> 
            </div>
        </form> 
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

index.js (these are the routes)

```
router.post('/searchkeyemail', async (req, res, next) => {
    const { search } = req.body;
    const newSearch = { 
        search: search
     };

    await pool.query("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE Email LIKE ?", [newSearch], (req, data) => {
        
    res.render('./perfil', { data: data});

    })
});



router.get('/perfil',  (req, res) => {
    res.render('perfil.ejs' )
});
```

adcards.ejs (this is the EJS view where Im passing the data to)

```
 <div class="cssshowlaptopcampanas"> 
    <%  if(data.lenght!=0) {
        var i=1;
        data.forEach(function(data) { 
        
          %>
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;  max-width: 100%; flex-wrap: wrap; margin-left: 400px; font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; justify-content: space-around; margin-bottom: 30px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
        <div style="margin: 10px; margin-top: 30px; border-radius: 20px;">
            <span class="badge badge-success" style="width: 100px;"><%= req.data.status %></span>
            <div class="card" style="width: 19rem; border-radius: 20px;">
                <img src="/city2.png" class="card-img-top" alt="..." style=" border-bottom-left-radius: 0px; border-bottom-right-radius: 0px; border-top-right-radius: 20px; border-top-left-radius: 20px;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title" style="position: relative; top: 7px;"><%= req.data.titulo %></h5>
                    </div>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                            <li class="list-group-item">Fecha inicio: <span style="font-weight: bold;"><%= req.data.fechas %></span>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">Mostrando en: <span style="font-weight: bold;"><%= req.data.zonas %></span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="card-body" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-around; background-color: #6351ce; color: white; border-bottom-right-radius: 20px; border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;">
                            <a href="#" class="card-link" style="color: white;">Editar</a>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% i++; }) %>
  <% } else { %>
    
    
<div class="card border-secondary mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-header">Oops</div>
    <div class="card-body text-secondary">
      <h5 class="card-title">No anuncios encontrados</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Busca tus anuncios digitando tu correo eletrónico</p>
    </div>
  </div>

    <% } %>

</div>
```

The perfil.ejs file is where the form is and the adcards.ejs file is where Im passing the data to. Im using them as partials in the same main file main.ejs . Not sure if there's an issue with using them in the same file.

I'd appreciate if someone can help me!

Comment: Not that cause of your problem, but `lenght` is a typo

Comment: Whatever `pool.query` is, I'm betting the callback pattern is `(error, data) =>`. I'm not sure why you've named the error parameter `req` but you aren't checking it to see if there are any database errors.

Comment: I'm also betting if you are using anonymous  database parameters (`?`) then it's expect the second argument to `query` to be an array of primitives (a string in this case), not objects.